# Marker move with map grab

Tags: openlayers

I have a problem, i defined an event when i click on the map, i move my marker on the position clicked. It works but when i want to move my map (by clicking/grab), it move also my marker (sound legit but i don't want that).

Here the code of the event for moving the marker :

```
// On créé un nouvel event click afin de déplacer le marker déjà placé sur la map 
map.events.register("click", map , function(e){
    var opx = map.getLayerPxFromViewPortPx(e.xy);
    marker.map = map;
    marker.moveTo(opx);
}
```

How can i grab my map without moving my marker (stay on the same lat/lon position) ?

Edit :
Here the complete function code if it can help:

```
function initPageCarto() {
        //niveau de zoom 
        zoom=12;

        var scale= new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({ topInUnits: 'km', bottomInUnits: 'm'});

        // gestion de la carto 
        var options = {
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                units: "m",
                maxResolution: 156543.0339,
                numZoomLevels: 18,
                controls: [
                        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                        scale]
        };

        map = new OpenLayers.Map("grandecarte",options);
        var newL = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Default", "serveurDeTuile", {numZoomLevels: 19});
        map.addLayer(newL);

        // récupération du polygone 
        var format = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT({
            'internalProjection': map.baseLayer.projection,
            'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        });

        var polygonFeature= format.read("<?php echo $polygone; ?>");
        // Centre du polygone 
        var center=polygonFeature.geometry.getCentroid();
        // Ajout de la couche vignette de localite 
        renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
        renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;

        // Creation du vectorlayer avec style 
        vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Simple Geometry", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                fillColor: "#3C8DBC",
                fillOpacity: 0.1,
                strokeColor: "#3C8DBC",
                strokeOpacity: 1
            }),
            renderers: renderer
        });

        // Ajout du polygone 
        vectorLayer.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);

        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

        markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
        markers.id = "Markers";
        map.addLayer(markers);

        map.events.register("click", map, function(e) {
            // On récupére la position afin de placer un marker 
            var position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);

            var posi = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
            var newlon = posi.lon;
            var newlat = posi.lat;

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lon="+newlon+"&lat="+newlat,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp : "callback",
                jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback",
                data: {
                    format:"json",
                    json_callback: 'jsonpCallback'
                },
                success: function ( data ) {
                    if(data.address) {
                        document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value = "";
                        document.getElementById('adresse').value = "";
                        if (data.address.house_number) {
                            document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += data.address.house_number;
                            document.getElementById('adresse').value += data.address.house_number;
                        }
                        if (data.address.road) {
                            if(document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value != "") {
                                document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += " ";
                                document.getElementById('adresse').value += " ";
                            }
                            document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += data.address.road;
                            document.getElementById('adresse').value += data.address.road;
                        }
                        if (data.address.postcode) {
                            if(document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value != "") {
                                document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += " ";
                            }
                            document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += data.address.postcode;
                            document.getElementById('cp').value = data.address.postcode;
                        }
                        if (data.address.city) {
                            if (document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value != "") {
                                    document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += " ";
                            }
                                document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += data.address.city;
                            document.getElementById('ville').value = data.address.city;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value = data.display_name;
                    }
                    document.getElementById('lat').value = data.lat;
                    document.getElementById('lon').value = data.lon;
                    document.getElementById('bbox').value = data.boundingbox;
                },
            });

            var size = new OpenLayers.Size(30,38);
            var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
            var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon("http://dokuwikispatial.sourceforge.net/dokuwiki/lib/plugins/openlayersmap/icons/marker-blue.png", size, offset);   

            marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(position,icon) ;
            markers.addMarker(marker);

            // On supprime l'event de click sur la map pour création d'un nouveau marker 
            map.events.remove('click');

            // On créé un nouvel event click afin de déplacer le marker déjà placé sur la map 
            map.events.register("click", map , function(e){
                var opx = map.getLayerPxFromViewPortPx(e.xy);
                marker.map = map;
                marker.moveTo(opx);

                var posi = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
                var newlon = posi.lon;
                var newlat = posi.lat;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lon="+newlon+"&lat="+newlat,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    jsonp : "callback",
                    jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback",
                    data: {
                        format:"json",
                        json_callback: 'jsonpCallback'
                    },
                    success: function ( data ) {
                        if(data.address) {
                            document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value = "";
                            document.getElementById('adresse').value = "";
                            if (data.address.house_number) {
                                    document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += data.address.house_number;
                                document.getElementById('adresse').value += data.address.house_number;
                            }
                            if (data.address.road) {
                                if (document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value != "") {
                                        document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += " ";
                                    document.getElementById('adresse').value += " ";
                                }
                                    document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += data.address.road;
                                document.getElementById('adresse').value += data.address.road;
                            }
                            if (data.address.postcode) {
                                if (document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value != "") {
                                        document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += " ";
                                }
                                    document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += data.address.postcode;
                                document.getElementById('cp').value = data.address.postcode;
                            }
                            if (data.address.city) {
                                if (document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value != "") {
                                        document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += " ";
                                }
                                    document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value += data.address.city;
                                document.getElementById('ville').value = data.address.city;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                                document.getElementById('searchbox_from_location').value = data.display_name;
                        }
                        document.getElementById('lat').value = data.lat;
                        document.getElementById('lon').value = data.lon;
                        document.getElementById('bbox').value = data.boundingbox;
                    },
                });
            });
        });

        // On construit la bounding box en fonction des min / max du polygone 
        map.zoomToExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds(<?php echo $min_x; ?>,<?php echo $min_y; ?>,<?php echo $max_x; ?>,<?php echo $max_y; ?>).transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913"));
    }
```

Comment: You mean you want the marker to stay in the same pixel postion, not geography position?

Comment: No, i want it to stay in the same geography position but it move to the position where i click to grab the map.

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior. You move the map, all vectors move with it. Perhaps I haven't understood the issue. Maybe you could post a complete working example, jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: It's hard to explain. I want my marker to move on the position i click on the map (which is working) but when i want to move my map (by left click + move mouse) when i release the left click, it also move my marker to the position clicked to move the map (and i don't want that).

i'll try to post a fiddle or screenshots to explain it better.

Comment: So, you want the marker to stay in the same relative position as the map, when you drag the map?

Comment: I want my marker to stay in the same geography position (lat,lon) when i drag the map.

Comment: That is the expected behavior. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I just update with the complete function code, don't know if it can help to see the problem